# Show different messages in JTextArea in Java Swing after clicking a button

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, event-dispatch-thread

I have a program with a button that does something N times and after each time, I want to see a log of it in a JTextArea. I want to click the button, have the program go through a for loop N times and after each time, tell me in a JTextArea something like "This is the N time I do this".

This is the code of my button:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (next) {
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * ((75 - 35) + 1)) + 35;
            //Do other things (add something to a DB)
            try {
                textarea.append("Loop number: "+i+". I'm gonna wait " + random + " seconds before continuing.\n");
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(random);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Ventana.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            textarea.append("I'm done.\n");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if I click the button, the program does everything and then after completing all the loops, all the messages show at the same time after finishing.

Is there a way to have a log like that in my program? Without using System.out.println.

Thank you!

EDIT: Some more information:
There will be nothing next, that's all that it does. 
It's just a window like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tfeo.png)
The code is called after clicking that button.

Comment: what is next? how is this code called? where is it called? you'll need to provide more context

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.